# Return an error response body for method not found - spring rest webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-boot

We are using spring boot for our application. We have a rest controller which has many methods and one of the method is like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/{id}/cards", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getCards(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws JsonMappingException, IOException
```

If there is any other request made to this url other than GET, for example it gives different status codes for different request, if the method type is DELETE it returns 405, if it is of type LINK it returns 501 without body.

How can I return a common status code 405 with error body?

Comment: Question is 'What is the easiest way'. Does not specify a problem.

Comment: The problem is it gives different status codes for different request, if the method type is DELETE it returns 405, if it is of type LINK it returns 501 and i would want to see how can i get a common code with error body

Comment: Why would you want less descriptive response codes

Comment: That is my team's decision, to have a common approach saying Method Not Allowed with body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring supports for global `@ExceptionHandler` with new `@ControllerAdvice` annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

Source: [Check here for more detail](http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/)